# Relocate Views' pager

Tags: views, theming, paging

I'd like to relocate the pager generated by views and put it, in my page.tpl.php part, in order to display it at the very bottom of the page.

Is this possible?

I tried copying this code from a view to page.tpl.php but it didn't work:

```
  <?php if ($pager): ?>
    <?php print $pager; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying this code snippet into your `page.tpl.php` won't help because the `$page` variable will not be defined for this template. You can only move it freely inside the `views-view.tpl.php` template.

You can add a similar `$pager` variable to your page template using your theme or module's implementation of [`hook_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7). In this implementation, you can retrieve the current page's view (if any) using [`views_get_current_view()`](http://api.lullabot.com/views_get_current_view). See the `template_preprocess_views_view()` function in Views' `include/theme.inc` for how to generate the pager from a view object. In Views 3.x the pager is build by the query plugin.